# how could I write some code containing flask and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, flask

I need to display the results of my script in Python using pandas which contain `group by`, but I couldn't. What I want actually is to see my result (from my script) on my website.

This the code I tried, it did not give a result

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def show_tables():  # put application's code here
    df = pd.read_csv('Cmaregraphe.csv', sep='[;\s]+', engine='python')
    p = df.groupby(['Date', 'Hour'])['Niveau'].mean()  # here it's just the function i need to show or use whatever
    return p.to_csv('Cmaregraphe.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string for route or use `render_template`. Create a template folder in your root and add index.html. You need to use [Jinja2](https://www.fullstackpython.com/jinja2.html) to render the python data as html.

Comment: what is jinja2???

Comment: could you please write the code i didn't get what do you mean by the last sentence

Comment: hey could you please write the code i didn't get what do you mean by the last sentence